# Inserting Link into The Content of the Cell That Shows Information on Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, linker, cell

I have an uncertain question that I want to ask.

Is it possible to insert a link (not website hyperlink) into the content of the cell that shows information on another sheet?

For example --> I have two sheets:
Sheet 1: Lending & Funding
Sheet 2: Company Information

On *Lending & Funding* sheet I have several information with 7500 data(s)/rows:
Column A: Client Name
Column B: Annual Sales
Column C: Interest

On *Company Information* Sheet I also have the same information:
Column A: Client Name
Column B: Annual Sales
Column C: Interest

Lets's say, in *Lending & Funding* sheet, I have PT.Microsoft in column A, Annual Sales: $3.500.000, and Interest: 9% (They are in the same row).

What I want is whenever I click one of the contents in column A (PT. Microsoft for example), the *Company Information* sheet will appear like a pop up and shows the data of PT.Microsoft based on *Lending & Funding* information.

Is that possible to do so?

I'm really okay if macro excel code or vlookup/indexmatch formula is necessary for this kind of case. Maybe you guys can write me the code as well :)

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below create a hyperlink to the name of a sheet in a cell, you can do the same thing to implement hyperlink to a cell. You can also attached a macro to a hyperlink.

```
Sub CreateSheetsHyperlinks()

'Declarations
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
 
i = 1

'Loop on all sheets
For Each Sh In Worksheets
     
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Select 'Select a value

    'Add the hyperlink in A1
    Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", _
        SubAddress:=Sh.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=Sh.Name

    i = i + 1
 
Next Sh
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a simple solution. Select Both Data sets and press CTRL+T to turn your data sets into a table.
Lending sheet is Table1 and the other is Table3 in my example.
On the Lending sheet press ALT+D+L to open data validation menu. When open select the "list" option from the ALLOW drop down. The SOURCE area wants to know where your getting your list from. Hover over the header on the lending sheet until you see a black arrow pointing down. this will select that column as your list and then it will enable you to continue to enter data in the table and you drop down will update. After that just copy the formula in the picture and rename the tables as you see fit.

```
=INDEX(Table3[@],
MATCH('Lending and Funding sheet'!$E$2,
     Table3[@[Client Name]:[Client Name]],0),
MATCH('Lending and Funding sheet'!F1,
     Table3[#Headers],0))
```

[image]